# c++ get unknown data type input from user

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012, user-input, auto

I am new to C++ and I am trying to create a program that gets an unknown data type input from a user and stores it in a variable. I am programming using visual studios and the code keeps producing error messages: E0304, LNK2019 and LNK1120.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
T dataEntered() {
T data;
std::cout << "Enter Data" << std::endl;
std::cin >> data;
return data;
}

int main()
{
    auto data = dataEntered();
    std::cout << sizeof(data) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}`
```

Comment: Templates are deduced at compile time. You can't make it depend on what happens when you run the program. What you could do instead is take input to a `std::string` and then parse the input and convert it to the data type that fits.

Answer (score 0):

`Template` is not the solution unless you will use it in this way:

```
auto data1 = dataEntered<char>();
auto data2 = dataEntered<int>();
std::cout << sizeof(data1) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(data2) << std::endl;
```

You should pass the type parameter so its known at compile time.

If you do not know the data until `run-time` I recommend that you read the data as **`string`** then write a `function` to **parse** it as you need.

Comment: Even if this makes OPs code compile, it's clearly not what he's asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Templates and autos are deduced at compile time, where autos are basically changed into the type deduced from the initialization value, and a version of the templated version is generated for every type used in the template parameter.

If you need to perform operations on the input, figure out what type the input is before reading it. You can also input it into a string and parse it later.

If you don't need to parse the input, just input into a string.

For example, if the first character of the input is a digit, it's probably a number.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    if(std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(std::cin.peek())))
    {
        //the input is a number
        int num;
        std::cin >> num;
        //do stuff with num
    }
    else
    {
        //input is something else
        std::string str;
        std::cin >> str;
        //do stuff with str;
    }
}
```